# Build separate assemblies within same project Visual Studio.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2008, assemblies, building

I've searched online for the answer to this but with no luck.

I was wondering if it was possible to build certain classes and or .cs files to separate assemblies within the same project?

I.e I have a number of HttpHandlers in one project, currently I am building them all into one assembly HttpHandlers, but what I was thinking if later I wanted to change the code in one of the Handlers I would need to rebuild the whole assembly, and possibly introduce problems with the other Handlers even though I haven't changed the code. I thought it would be best to keep them autonomous so an update to one handler would in no way affect the others. Ofcourse I could create separate projects but I was wondering if it was possible to do this within the same project.

I'm using VS2008 Pro.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use separate projects?

Comment: I've already have 6 projects and if I split them that would be another 4 projects. I could and probably will do that but was wondering if there was a way to do it within the same project, just thought it would be tidier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do that with [Multi-file Assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grantri/archive/2004/07/07/175745.aspx). But it's a lot of work.

Comment: Hi. I've already decided to use multiple projects within the one Solution as it's tidy enough and the least problematic solution. I did have a look at your link and I think you are right, it's a lot of work for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: *I accidentally posted to the wrong question (multiple tabs opened - my bad). This solution is for the opposite problem: how to merge multiple assemblies into one single .exe*.

I looked into the same issue today and found [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) from MS Research.

I had a simple WinForms app and just wanted to see something quickly.
Here is what I ran in my main projects bin\Debug directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe"
  /targetplatform:v4,"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5"
  /target:winexe /wildcards /out:TheNewMerged.exe TheOld.exe *.dll

copy TheOld.exe.config TheNewMerged.exe.config
```

The "/targetplatform" switch is to fix an issue with ILMerge throwing an "Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Core" exception.

My project was compiled with v4.5 - adjust this for your project.

[Other people](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/06/02/ilmerge---unresolved-assembly-reference-not-allowed-system.core.aspx) have suggested fixing the issue by creating an ILMerge.exe.config file.
It will certainly make the command-line shorter :-)